# Send data to a REST API every time a new account is added to Salesforce

Tags: api, rest, salesforce, integration

Sorry for the total newbie question here regarding triggers, but here is my scenerio:

What are some of the options available to send data to a 3rd party REST API every time a new account is added to Salesforce?

I have been initially looking at code examples for triggers on account after insert. In addition to this, is there a way using the SFDC streaming API? Any ideas on What API usage is best practice + code examples would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to make callout from a trigger you need to make the callout asynchronous (using @future annotation) .

For example :

```
trigger  AfterInsertAccount on Account (after insert){
    futCls.asynchCallout(); //call a method with @future annotation  
}
```

Class Code :

```
global futCls {
@future 
Public static void asynchCallout(callout=true){
     HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
     req.setEndpoint('your 3rd party service URL goes here');
     req.setMethod('GET'); 
     Http http = new Http();
     HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
 }
}
```

For more information refer to SFDC documentation.